# How to update the initialData of "useState" from parent in Flutter Hooks

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hooks

According to the description of [useState](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useState.html) in [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks):

```
... 
/// On the first call, it initializes [ValueNotifier] to [initialData]. [initialData] is ignored
/// on subsequent calls.
...
```

I want to use `useState` to change the current widget state. I also want the initialData **NOT** to be ignored when the value is changed from the parent. How to achieve it?

```
class MyHookWidget extends HookWidget {
  const MyHookWidget({required this.valueFromParent, super.key});

  final int valueFromParent;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final state = useState<int>(valueFromParent);
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came cross it by using **useEffect** or **useValueChanged**, which is like
[didUpdateWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) for StatefulWidget.

### [useEffect](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useEffect.html)

> Useful for side-effects and optionally canceling them.
>
> useEffect is called synchronously on every build, unless keys is
> specified. In which case useEffect is called again only if any value
> inside keys as changed.
>
> It takes an effect callback and calls it synchronously. That effect
> may optionally return a function, which will be called when the effect
> is called again or if the widget is disposed.
>
> By default effect is called on every build call, unless keys is
> specified. In which case, effect is called once on the first useEffect
> call and whenever something within keys change/

Example:

```
final state = useState<int>(valueFromParent);

useEffect(() {
  state.value = valueFromParent;
  return () {};
}, [valueFromParent]);
```

### [useValueChanged](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useValueChanged.html)

> Watches a value and triggers a callback whenever the value changed.
>
> useValueChanged takes a valueChange callback and calls it whenever
> value changed. valueChange will not be called on the first
> useValueChanged call.
>
> useValueChanged can also be used to interpolate Whenever
> useValueChanged is called with a different value, calls valueChange.
> The value returned by useValueChanged is the latest returned value of
> valueChange or null.

Example:

```
final state = useState<int>(valueFromParent);

useValueChanged(
  valueFromParent,
  (_, __) => state.value = valueFromParent,
);
```